# Having a little trouble with OleDataAdapter and getting a string result back

Tags: c#, wpf, oledbconnection

```
private string getPrinterPath()
{
     string query1 = "SELECT printerPath FROM Printers WHERE printerFloor = '" + comboBoxFloor.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND printerNumber = " + textBoxPrinterNumber.Text.ToString();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
     da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query1, myDataConnection);
     da.Fill(dt);            
}
```

I am trying to get the String that is returned back from the execution of this query.

Can anyone please tell me how I can get the data from the DataAdapter?

I know I can

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   Console.WriteLine(dr["printerPath"].ToString());
}
```

but i am expecting 1 item returned so I don't want to run it in an loop when it's unnecessary

If there is a better way, please let me know.
I am also confused about how to "Parameterize" my query so I am not passing values in directly

Comment: I would recommend looking up how to use parameterized query. there are a lot of examples online as well as C# MSDN `OleDBCommand.Parameters.Add` Method.. also when you ask about `can anyone show you how to get data from the OleDBDataAdapter` have you stepped through the code..? after you call the `Fill` method.. what does the data look like in the `QuickWatch` when you click the little magnifying glass, do you see any rows or data..?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use "ExecuteScalar" for something like that, which just returns the first result of the first row of a query.

As for parameters, you would pass parameters to the command.

It would look something like this:

```
string query1,
    result;

query1 = "SELECT printerPath FROM Printers WHERE printerFloor = '?' AND printerNumber = ?";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(myDataConnection)) {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PrinterFloor", comboBoxFloor.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PrinterNum", textBoxPrinterNumber.Text.ToString());
    conn.Open();
    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: By the way, the parameters in an OleDbCommand don't really care about the name, it just looks at the order of the parameters being passed to it and where the placeholders (the question marks) in the query are.  So the order is important.  The names you give the parameters, however, are not. I think they are just added to aid in readability.

Comment: I tried your code and result = cmd.ExecuteScalar has an error. Can not convert object to string

Comment: What datatype is printerPath in your database?

Try making result an object (just declare object result; at the top) and then after your query, write it out as result.ToString()?

Comment: Or, if you are sure the result in your database is a string, I think you can also just do:

`result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: PrinterNum is defined as a Number in the database so I changed the parameter to Int32.Parse(textBoxPrinter.Text)

Comment: I get new errors when trying to cmd.ExecuteScalar Internal error in the expression evaluator.

Comment: Well your method did not work. I am sure it is a lot better than looping thru every DataRow (even if I'm expecting 1 record. However if someone made a mistake on the backend, then I could potentially get 2 records then the 2nd record would overwrite the first record)

Comment: I see.  I thought you were expecting only one record all the time. Then yeah, you don't want ExecuteScalar.

Comment: I am expecting 1 record. My table is setup with 3 columns. servername, floornumber and printerpath. I use the 1st two parameters to get the printerPath which is what i'll use later to install the printer. But we're human. Someone can add a duplicate entry or add a different pritnerPath to the same servername and floor number